# How can I test weather I'm being navigated to the correct url or not using jest for react?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

The line to test is

```
 <ButtonCTA text="Facebook" type="submit" onClick={() => {
                window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.legalzoom.com', '', 'status=1,width=575,height=520'); }}
              className="btn btn-action tw-block tw-py-0 tw-px-3 tw-flex tw-items-center
                tw-flex-row-reverse tw-text-16 tw-leading-6 tw-tracking-[-0.2px] tw-w-[192px]
                tw-justify-center tw-mr-3" testid='Facebook'>
            </ButtonCTA>
```

```
    const button = getByTestId(containerNode,'Facebook');
    userEvent.click(button);
    const url='https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://www.legalzoom.com';
    expect(window.location.href).toMatch(url);
```

In jest it navigates to Localhost so this code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to test the browser's behavior in tests. Because this behavior has already been tested by the Mozilla, Google, etc before the release. All you need to do is to test that the behavior is triggered correctly. In your situation it will be something like this:

```
// before the rendering
jest.spyOn(window, "open")
...
expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith('https://www.facebook.com/....');
```

If you really want to test such behavior you should use [cypress.io](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2021/04/06/cypress-component-testing-react/) which runs your code in real browser

Comment: Please suggest some could resources to learning testing for react and js

Comment: @shrcod it's better for you to read about the philosophy of unit testing. It is the core. Then you can go with testing for the react and js. I can suggest you this course https://javascript.ninja/workshops/unit-testing but it requires payment and it is in russian language.

Comment: Please suggest something in english, that would be great!

Comment: @shrcod you can check Kent C. Dodds's articals or courses https://kentcdodds.com/blog/static-vs-unit-vs-integration-vs-e2e-tests